# can I save Richtext files as a brand new file type that only my program can open (VB)

Tags: vb.net, file, text, file-type

I'm still a bit new to programming, but I'm trying to make a notepad application has a password before you can get in to the notepad part. (The login in page works mostly). However, I have two questions:

Can I make it so I when I save the program, it will save it as a document only my program can read? Because I wanted it to be password protected. However, MS word can open the text documents made from my program. I only want my program to be able to open and view what is created from that program.

Here is the code to save the current text:

```
Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Try
            Dim dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
            dlg.Title = "Save"
            dlg.Filter = "Rich Text Files (*.rtf)|*.rtf"
            If dlg.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                RichTextBox1.SaveFile(dlg.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception : End Try
    End Sub
```

> (I copied this part of code from somewhere else)

The second question is:

I have two forms (`login and loginpassed`). If I pass the login I have set the login form to hide (because (Close) closes the whole program even the login passed form. and if I click the red X to close the loginpassed form, the login form is still running, how can I close the first form without closing the second form?

Comment: If you have a second question, create a new post and ask it there. This is a Question and Answer site (note that Question is not plural). Richtext is a plain text format, which means any application that can open a text file can open your file. If you want it to not be able to be opened by other apps, you'll need to take steps to protect it such as encryption.

Comment: You can't prevent other applications opening your files if they understand the format. All files are only bytes and any application can open any file if it understands what those bytes mean. You can save any file with any extension and you can register any extension on a computer but that doesn't change what's inside.

Comment: [**I asked a question about this**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a981349-db9a-4c38-9b57-1533d430c861/fixing-my-own-file-extension-so-that-for-example-notepad-cannot-read-it?forum=vbgeneral) on the MSDN forum two years ago (see the second answer).